# Google Maps not getting exact location on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, maps

I'm making an application in Android (with Kotlin) that requires Google Maps services. When a button is pressed, it should locate me. However it is not accurate at all.

I use this version of Google Maps:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
```

Another versions:

- Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1
- Tested with: Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 and Xiaomi Litte 9

And this is the code when I press the button:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*

private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private var coordinatesUbication: LatLng? = null

private fun getMyUbication() {
    if (isGPSPermissions() && isGPSActive()) {
        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false

        // 1) Get latitude and longitude of the current position.
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            val location = task.result

            if (location != null) {
                // 2) Get coordinates.
                val coordinates: LatLng? = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                this@MapsFragment.coordinatesUbication = coordinates

                // 3) Set camera position.
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    cameraPosition(coordinatesUbication, Constants.CAMERA_ZOOM)
                }
            }
        }

    } else if (!isGPSPermissions()) {
        myUbication = true
        showDialogPermissions()
    } else {
        myUbication = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put key to **res->values->google_maps_api.xml**?

Comment: You implemented returns the most recent historical location currently available according to the given request. Use current loction callback